# append some value to integer array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer

```
import numpy as np

c=[4,8,2,3........]
a=np.array([2,3,5],np.int16) #data type=np.int16=Integer(-32768 +32767))


for i in range(len(c)): 
    a.append(c[i]) # This line getting error
```

how can I add some value to this integer array "a" using append or any other method?

Comment: You really don't want to do that. It sounds like you want a `list` instead of an array. In fact, you cannot append to a `numpy` array in-place. You can make a *whole new* array, though. The major limitation of a `numpy` array is that it is fixed-size.

Comment: I just want to speed up my array loop. Array c[] is too much large . That's why I want store my values as integers

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  `c` is **not an array, it is a list**. What array loop? If you want to make a `numpy.ndarray` out of list `c` then you only need to do `a = np.array(c, np.int16)`

Comment: A Numpy array isn't an extendible list, it's a fixed-sized array. There are [functions for changing an array's size and shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html), but you normally set the array to the size you want and then populate it with the data. Expanding it item by item to add new data would be very inefficient.

Comment: FWIW, even a pure Python list doesn't really grow item by item. Internally, a CPython list over-allocates its data store so that multiple items can be appended before it needs to allocate more space. And it doesn't actually store the objects you put in it, it just stores a reference to them. If you can read C, you can see the details in the nicely-commented [listobject.c source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c).

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting an error is that you cannot append to `numpy.array`. If `a` was a `list`, you would have no problem.

It looks like this is what you are looking for:

```
In [4]: a = [2,3,5]

In [5]: c = [4,8,2,3]

In [6]: a.extend(c)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: [2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 3]
```

If `a` and `c` are `numpy.arrays`, you can:

```
In [12]: a = np.array([2,3,5])

In [13]: c = np.array([4,8,2,3])

In [14]: np.concatenate((a,c))
Out[14]: array([2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well according to the docs the numpy arrays do not have the function **append**.

Here is the correction of your code:

```
import numpy as np

c=[4,8,2,3........]
a=np.array([2,3,5],np.int16) #data type=np.int16=Integer(-32768 +32767))


for i in range(len(c)): 
    a = np.append(a, c[i]) # This line getting error
```

I guess this was what you wanted to do, according to the docs [numpy.append()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) is a free function that you can use. I hope this helps you.

Comment: `np.append(a, c[i])` is inefficient, because for every value in `c`,  `a` would have to be copied over and a new `array` would have to be created.

Comment: @Sebas: Did you try running this? It doesn't work, because `np.append` doesn't modify `a` in-place, so `a` is unmodified by the line `np.append(a, c[i])`. You need `a = np.append(a, c[i])` instead.

Comment: Yes, Numpy _does_ have an append function, but it's not intended to be used for building arrays from scratch, and it's definitely not wise to use it create an array by adding items to it one at a time. As you can see from my answer, that approach is _very_ slow in comparison to creating the array at its full size, although if you  pass `numpy.append` decent-sized lists rather than single items then it's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are much more efficient at item-wise construction than numpy arrays.  If you want to `append` one-by-one, I would suggest appending to a list and then converting it to a numpy array using `np.array(myList)`.  A faster way to do the same thing your code does is this:

```
a = np.array(list(a) + c, np.int16)
```

If you just want to convert your `c` list into an `int16` array:

```
c = np.array(c, np.int16)
```

Which you can then `np.concatenate` as per @Akavall or use the somewhat more compact `np.r_` form (note the square brackets).

```
a = np.r_[a,c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) code that compares the speeds of 3 different ways of converting a 2D Python list of small integers to a 1D Numpy array.

The straight-forward way is to simply pass the whole list to Numpy's `array` function, and then flatten the resulting 2D array to 1D via its `.flatten` method. That's the approach taken by `grid_to_array`.

The other ways that I tested both use the `numpy.append` function. `grid_rows_to_array` builds the array row by row, `grid_items_to_array` builds it item by item. As you might guess, this last approach is *very* slow. Even for a 10x10 list it's around 50 times slower than `grid_to_array`. For larger lists, it's speed is truly glacial.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Compare the speeds of various functions that convert a 
    2D integer list to a 1D Numpy array.

    See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44512661/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2017.06.13
'''

import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer

def make_grid(n):
    ''' Make a 2D list of integers '''
    return [list(range(i, i + n)) for i in range(0, n * n, n)]

# The functions to test

def grid_to_array(g):
    ''' Create a 2D array from the whole grid and convert it to 1D '''
    return np.array(g).flatten()

def grid_rows_to_array(g):
    ''' Create a 1D array from the 1st row of the grid,
        then append all the other rows to it, row by row
    '''
    # An iterator that yields the rows
    it = iter(g)
    a = np.array(next(it))
    for row in it:
        a = np.append(a, row)
    return a

def grid_items_to_array(g):
    ''' Create an array from the 1st item of the grid,
        then append all the other items to it, item by item
    '''
    # A generator that yields the items
    gen = (u for row in g for u in row)
    a = np.array(next(gen))
    for u in gen:
        a = np.append(a, u)
    return a

funcs = (
    grid_to_array,
    grid_rows_to_array,
    grid_items_to_array,
)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

def verify(size):
    ''' Verify that all the functions give the same result '''

    print('Grid rows, size=', size)
    grid = make_grid(size)
    for row in grid:
        print(row)
    print()

    results = []
    for func in funcs:
        print(func.__name__)
        a = func(grid)
        print(a, '\n')
        results.append(a)

    # Test that all arrays are identical
    first, *results = results
    rc = all((first == u).all() for u in results)
    print('all ok' if rc else 'Error!')
    return rc

def time_test(loops, reps):
    ''' Print timing stats for all the functions '''
    timings = []
    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.__name__
        setup = 'from __main__ import grid, ' + fname
        cmd = fname + '(grid)'
        t = Timer(cmd, setup)
        result = t.repeat(reps, loops)
        result.sort()
        timings.append((result, fname))

    timings.sort()
    for result, fname in timings:
        print('{:20} {}'.format(fname, result))

verify(5)

# Do the timing tests
reps = 3
loops = 128
for i in range(6):
    size = 10 * (2 ** i)
    grid = make_grid(size)
    print('\n{0}: Size={1}, Loops={2}'.format(i, size, loops))
    time_test(loops, reps)
    loops >>= 1
```

**output**

```
Grid rows, size= 5
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

grid_to_array
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24] 

grid_rows_to_array
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24] 

grid_items_to_array
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24] 

all ok

0: Size=10, Loops=128
grid_to_array        [0.007200194995675702, 0.01232630800222978, 0.014947812996979337]
grid_rows_to_array   [0.047056858995347284, 0.04709799499687506, 0.047196302002703305]
grid_items_to_array  [0.4025771490050829, 0.40894141500029946, 0.4112219040034688]

1: Size=20, Loops=64
grid_to_array        [0.009614694004994817, 0.01012843299395172, 0.015028686997538898]
grid_rows_to_array   [0.0559136279989616, 0.05666288200154668, 0.08348615399881965]
grid_items_to_array  [0.8405412119973334, 0.8444936599989887, 0.8777696510005626]

2: Size=40, Loops=32
grid_to_array        [0.018018493996351026, 0.019878495004377328, 0.023297555999306496]
grid_rows_to_array   [0.06234459100232925, 0.06246465100412024, 0.06281185599800665]
grid_items_to_array  [1.7235709279993898, 1.7587534330014023, 1.8295516790021793]

3: Size=80, Loops=16
grid_to_array        [0.029057150000880938, 0.03226659999927506, 0.03832875600346597]
grid_rows_to_array   [0.08397659000183921, 0.08470724899962079, 0.0852264919958543]
grid_items_to_array  [3.7167786709978827, 3.8199421919998713, 4.046950017000199]

4: Size=160, Loops=8
grid_to_array        [0.06241827599296812, 0.06254585299757309, 0.07094153799698688]
grid_rows_to_array   [0.14922553599899402, 0.1522045050005545, 0.15509943600045517]
grid_items_to_array  [11.045316871000978, 11.064624926999386, 12.66077643600147]

5: Size=320, Loops=4
grid_to_array        [0.13331966300029308, 0.1439433339983225, 0.15014286800578702]
grid_rows_to_array   [0.6806031250016531, 0.685745176000637, 0.7797461770023801]
grid_items_to_array  [162.62937470299948, 162.73040329200012, 167.80105410800024]
```

These timings were obtained using Python 3.6.0 on a rather ancient 2GHz single core 32 bit machine with 2GB of RAM, running a Debian derivative of Linux. YMMV.